# Javascript append file with variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, text

this code below will successfully write "apple" into the text file called save.txt

```
//Write Text File
var total = $gameActors.actor(1).name();
var path = window.location.pathname.replace(/(\/www|)\/[^\/]*$/, '/');
if (path.match(/^\/([A-Z]\:)/)) {
      path = path.slice(1);
}
path = decodeURIComponent(path) + "save.txt";
var fs = require('fs');
fs.appendFile('save.txt',"apple", function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('created]');
});
```

I want to write the variable "total" into the file

I have tried

```
fs.appendFile('save.txt',total,
fs.appendFile('save.txt',var total,
fs.appendFile('save.txt',(total),
```

but none works.
Any help is appreciated Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var total = $gameActors.actor(1).name();
if( !total ){ total = 0; }

fs.appendFile('save.txt', total, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('created');
});
```